# SoundCloud widget volume gets reset to 100 when next song is played

Tags: soundcloud

If you use setVolume() to lower the volume of the SoundCloud widget, when the SoundCloud player plays the next song, it resets the volume to 100.

You can reproduce the problem on the SoundCloud API playground page.

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

To reproduce:

1. start playing the song
2. set the volume to 20
3. press "get volume" (shows 20)
4. press "next"
5. press "get volume" (shows 100)

[image: SoundCloud Widget API Playground]